# Show same columns with different values (and empty values)

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

i'm quite new to SQL and i'm having this issues.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(WeekNr int,
Name varchar(30),
Value int)

INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (21,'John',100)
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (21,'Michael',133)
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (21,'Tony',50)
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (22,'John',80)
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (23,'Michael',188)
INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (23,'Tony',230)
```

Table shows this way:

```
  WeekNr         Name        Value
  21             John        100
  21             Michael     133
  21             Tony        50
  22             John        80
  23             Michael     188
  23             Tony        230
```

I need to arrange data in this way:

```
  Name           Vale          Name         Value        Name        Value
  John           100           John          80          Michael     188
  Michael        133                                     Tony        230
  Tony           50
```

where the first two columns refers to WeekNr being 21, the second two to WeekNr being 22, and then WeekNr being 23.

It would be better if Null values will be included so without skipping any WeekNr. For example if i do something like

```
  DELETE FROM #TempTable WHERE WeekNr = 22
```

It should appear something like:

```
  Name           Vale          Name         Value        Name        Value
  John           100                                     Michael     188
  Michael        133                                     Tony        230
  Tony           50
```

so it's easy to export data to Excel.
Do i need to use PIVOT or UNPIVOT?

Comment: it could be a front end job?

Comment: Yes, i also thought to do this in the front end. Or store the data in a temporary table and then select them with a simple where condition. I suppose it's the best way... but since i had struggle with this problem in the last 2 days i was wondering how to do it just with a single query...

Comment: did you tried pradeep code? i think this works..and your question is realistic.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT Max([21]) NAME,Max([id21]) Value,Max([22]) Name,Max([id22]) Value,Max([23]) Name,Max([id23]) Value
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY WeekNr ORDER BY NAME) rn,
               NAME,value,WeekNr,
               'id' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WeekNr)      AS weeks
        FROM   #TempTable) a
       PIVOT (Max(NAME)
             FOR WeekNr IN ([21],[22],[23])) piv 
       PIVOT (max(value) 
             FOR weeks IN ([id21],[id22],[id23])) piv1
GROUP BY rn
```

If you want the code to work dynamically then try this.

```
DECLARE @cols     VARCHAR(max)='',
        @cols1    VARCHAR(max)='',
        @aggcols  VARCHAR(max)='',
        @aggcols1 VARCHAR(max)='',
        @sql      NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @cols += ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), weeknr)+']',
       @cols1 += ',[id' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), weeknr)+']',
       @aggcols += ',max([' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), weeknr)+ ']) Name',
       @aggcols1 += ',max([id' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), weeknr)+ ']) Value'
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT WeekNr
        FROM   #TempTable) A 

select @cols= RIGHT(@cols,len(@cols)-1)
select @cols1= RIGHT(@cols1,len(@cols1)-1)

select @aggcols= RIGHT(@aggcols,len(@aggcols)-1)
select @aggcols1= RIGHT(@aggcols1,len(@aggcols1)-1)

set @sql ='SELECT '+@aggcols+','+@aggcols1+'
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER(partition BY WeekNr ORDER BY NAME) rn,
               NAME,value,WeekNr,
               ''id'' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, WeekNr)      AS weeks
        FROM   #TempTable) a
       PIVOT (Max(NAME)
             FOR WeekNr IN ('+@cols+')) piv 
       PIVOT (max(value) 
             FOR weeks IN ('+@cols1+')) piv1
GROUP BY rn'


exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you are supposed to do with SQL. **Don't do it with SQL**, it would be complex to develop and maintain.

SQL helps you retrieve your data, you are able to do some kind of presentation stuff, but as soon as it becomes too complex, you know you are having the wrong approach. **You should do this kind of presentation in your front end application**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in SQL Server either, as a matter a fact, I'm fairly new to it. I don't think this is possible in any easy way. The best thing I can think of is by running three different queries, where you would have a Where condition stating something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Value
FROM #TempTable
WHERE WeekNr = 21
GO

SELECT Name, Value
FROM #TempTable
WHERE WeekNr = 22
GO

SELECT Name, Value
FROM #TempTable
WHERE WeekNr = 23
GO
```

Then when you would run the whole query, it would give you three windows of data, but not organized exactly the way you want it. The problem is that if you have hundreds or thousands of those WeekNr values, this becomes almost impossible to implement and run that way.

Comment: WeeksNr runs through 1 to 52